# Django and ImageField Question

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Foo (models.Model):
        slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')

I want to do two things with this:

First of all, I want my image to be forced to resize to a specific width and height after the upload.
I have tried this reading the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) but seems to getting error:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', height_field=258, width_field=425)
```

Secondly, when adding an item via admin panel, I want my image's file name to be renamed as same as slug, if any issue arises (like if such named image already exists, add "_" to the end as it used to do.
IE: My slug is i-love-you-guys , uploaded image such have i-love-you-guys.png at the end.

Answer (score 2):

[Signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/signals/#topics-signals) are the answer to both of your questions.

As stated in the docs, the height_field and width_field are names of fields where to store the original image's height and width -- not to coerce the image to a certain size. I think the best way to handle what you want to do is to use either the pre_save or post_save signal to resize the image using PIL.  You may also want to check out [sorl](http://code.google.com/p/sorl-thumbnail/).  In fact, you can use the sorl's thumbnail in your signal to create the new image.

To rename the filename, also use a signal.